# CLion can find the MinGW64, but it takes no effect. I still can't run C/C++ programs

Tags: c++, c, clion

After I download the CLion, I configure MinGW-64 also.

I've tried almost everything online, and they're surprisingly consistent, but they still don't solve my problem.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I know it's just a simple configuration issue, but I spent the whole day and still couldn't solve it.

Can someone help me? I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I am not familiar with CLion but you probably need to explain better where the problem occurs. Does it compile? Does it produce an executable?

Comment: @drescherjm Sorry. It cannot compile to build executable.

Comment: Is there any type of error reported in the IDE. Did you look at the folders with your files? Did the CMake generate a makefile?

Comment: did you try this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-tutorial-on-configuring-clion-on-windows.html#Cygwin ?

Comment: @long.kl Let me have a try..

Comment: @drescherjm no error, just can't run it. And the 'CMakeList.txt' is so empty.

Comment: @long.kl still can't work.. Except 'MinGW' and 'Cygwin', are there any other environments that need to be configured?

Comment: or you can try with linux subsystem , it also is included in above link.

Comment: @long.kl it works! thanks a lot. I'll post the answer later!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to compile the c/c++ file, none of **Cygwin** and **MinGW** can be ignore!

Thanks for the brother's ([@long.kl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16331360/long-kl)) suggest!

just do as follows pictures, your c/c++ compile can work too.

> Note that the order

[image]

[image]